# Eclipse: "Activity not started" error

Tags: android, eclipse, emulation

Sometimes when I make a change to a source file in Eclipse (3.7.0) and Run | Run, the emulator gets loaded with the update and everything is fine.

Other times, I get the standard launch messages, then one last one in red:

ActivityManager: Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front

and it appears that the program did not get updated

I don't know what I'm doing different between the two cases. Any ideas?

TIA!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens when there are no changes in the code / resources.
Then all the Android plugin does is start the app which was already installed in the previous time you ran it.

If you're changing images or any resource / code outside the IDE, don't forget to refresh the project's contents before building.

Comment: Is there any way to override this behavior and force a restart? (with a single keystroke)

Comment: Not that I know of, but it's actually a time-saving behaviour in most cases... And it also should raise a flag that you forgot to refresh the assets/source.
Of course, the easy 4 clicks solution would be:
add a char to one of the sources,
delete the char,
save the file,
Build

Comment: Yes, that's the answer, thanks! I was editing some of the source files externally (with emacs). These files were not showing in an edit window of Eclipse so I assumed Eclipse would pull in the new ones, but apparently, that's not the case. My dumb solution... oh, I see, the comment above mine has the same idea.